# Drawing a polygon on user's location leaflet

Tags: geolocation, leaflet, polygon

I'm currently building a web app for a project and was wondering if anybody could help me. I'm basically making a GPS game where the whole map is covered in fog and to remove the fog user's have to visit each location and login.

For the fog I'm just going to use a giant polygon to cover the entire map and then using the user's location, generate a polygon at the user's current location, cut that polygon from the fog polygon and then finally re-apply it.

Could anybody advise me as to how I could add a hexagon shaped polygon at the users location.

I'm currently getting the user's location using the geolocation API but I'm also a little stumped as to draw the hexagon. Below I've got the location code which drops a marker on the user location and a basic static polygon(polygon is a placeholder nothing more).
I've tried playing the navigator code  to add a polygon at the users location but it keeps breaking the map and I'm a bit stumped as to how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var userMarker = L.marker([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]).addTo(mymap);
    })

    var userPolygon = [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-1.5268367528915405,54.98091997292441],
                    [-1.5270352363586424,54.98074450562538],
                    [-1.5267670154571533,54.98054748879672],
                    [-1.5262091159820557,54.980541332005245],
                    [-1.5259945392608643,54.98072911372045],
                    [-1.5262305736541748,54.98091689455734],
                    [-1.5268367528915405,54.98091997292441]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }].addTo(mymap);
```

Thank you @FalkeDesign for your help thus far. I've added the updated code below and would really appreciate if you could point out why they aren't showing

```
<script>


    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([57.149860, -2.102930], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    // //var to capture user position and place marker 
    // navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    //  var userMarker = L.marker([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]).addTo(mymap);
    // })

    var fog = L.rectangle([[54.98652836571122, -1.542469837492442], [54.973032422136875, -1.4963848081781708]]);
    var fogLayer = L.geoJSON(fog.toGeoJSON()).addTo(myMap);

    function subtract() {
        var radius = 0.01;
        var hex = createHex(myMap.getCenter(), radius); //replace center with navigator point
        var templayer = L.geoJSON(turf.difference(fogLayer.getLayers()[0].toGeoJSON(), hex.toGeoJSON()));
        fogLayer.removeFrom(myMap);
        fogLayer = templayer.addTo(myMap)
    }


    function createHex(center, radius) {
        var centerp = turf.point([center.lng, center.lat]);
        var points = [];
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, 90));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, 150));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, -150));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, -90));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, -30));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, 30));

        var hex = L.polygon([]);
        points.forEach((p) => {
            hex.addLatLng([p.geometry.coordinates[1], p.geometry.coordinates[0]]);
        });
        return hex;
    }

    subtract();
    myMap.on('move', subtract);







    ////Add custom user icon
    // var userIcon = L.icon({
    //  iconUrl: 'prototype\img\icons8-user-location-48.png',

    //  iconSize: [48, 48], // size of the icon
    //  shadowSize:   [0, 0], // size of the shadow
    //  iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location

    // });




    //Fog polygon
    var fogPolygon =
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {},
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                -175.078125,
                                84.9901001802348
                            ],
                            [
                                -174.375,
                                -85.05112877980659
                            ],
                            [
                                197.578125,
                                -84.92832092949963
                            ],
                            [
                                197.578125,
                                84.9901001802348
                            ],
                            [
                                -175.078125,
                                84.9901001802348
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    L.geoJSON(fogPolygon, {
        style: function (feature) {
            return {
                color: '#000000',
                weight: 0.2,
            }
        }
    }).addTo(mymap);








    /*PoI Placeholders*/
    var duthiePark = L.polygon([
        [57.12896, -2.107036],
        [57.12882, -2.101028],
        [57.130765, -2.097294],
        [57.132512, -2.102809],
        [57.131906, -2.107852],
        [57.130776, -2.106779]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var robertGordon = L.polygon([
        [57.119828, -2.150552],
        [57.117568, -2.148342],
        [57.117661, -2.136669],
        [57.118232, -2.129974],
        [57.11963, -2.130404],
        [57.119886, -2.136497],
        [57.118768, -2.14493]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var pittodrie = L.polygon([
        [57.159646, -2.090192],
        [57.158436, -2.090299],
        [57.158587, -2.086523],
        [57.159693, -2.086844],
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var unionTerraceGardens = L.polygon([
        [57.14575, -2.101521],
        [57.147612, -2.103775],
        [57.147612, -2.104461],
        [57.147147, -2.104826],
        [57.145598, -2.102122]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var unionSquare = L.polygon([
        [57.144166, -2.098882],
        [57.145098, -2.095771],
        [57.142653, -2.092767],
        [57.141582, -2.095771]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var marischalCollege = L.polygon([
        [57.150301, -2.096007],
        [57.149475, -2.097552],
        [57.14838, -2.096329],
        [57.149044, -2.095428],
        [57.14951, -2.095084],
        [57.150232, -2.095504],
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var robertGordonCollege = L.polygon([
        [57.147822, -2.1032177],
        [57.147868, -2.100663],
        [57.148858, -2.101521],
        [57.149638, -2.103066],
        [57.149381, -2.104053]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var robertGordonCollege = L.polygon([
        [57.147822, -2.1032177],
        [57.147868, -2.100663],
        [57.148858, -2.101521],
        [57.149638, -2.103066],
        [57.149381, -2.104053]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var aberdeenBeach = L.polygon([
        [57.142428, -2.068863],
        [57.145315, -2.073669],
        [57.153602, -2.078819],
        [57.164122, -2.079248],
        [57.173149, -2.077446],
        [57.158536, -2.078047],
        [57.147829, -2.074614],
        [57.1428, -2.06809]
    ]).addTo(mymap);


    var victoriaPark = L.polygon([
        [57.15256, -2.124707],
        [57.150599, -2.123762],
        [57.151966, -2.118838],
        [57.152781, -2.119181]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var westburnPark = L.polygon([
        [57.155969, -2.126412],
        [57.152664, -2.124674],
        [57.152845, -2.121574],
        [57.153648, -2.121187],
        [57.153625, -2.119911],
        [57.154934, -2.120233]
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var aberdeenHarbour = L.polygon([
        [57.14536, -2.095031],
        [57.145803, -2.093743],
        [57.146263, -2.087681],
        [57.144526, -2.075472],
        [57.142011, -2.069764],
        [57.140498, -2.075686],
        [57.140498, -2.089033]
    ]).addTo(mymap);


    var aberdeenUniversity = L.polygon([
        [57.166762, -2.106467],
        [57.167129, -2.10224],
        [57.166721, -2.097305],
        [57.16575, -2.097702],
        [57.164498, -2.097402],
        [57.164557, -2.099805],
        [57.163067, -2.099869],
        [57.163266, -2.102047],
        [57.161973, -2.101736],
        [57.162404, -2.10429],
        [57.16337, -2.107208],
        [57.165404, -2.106156],
    ]).addTo(mymap);

    var hazleheadPark = L.polygon([
        [57.142869, -2.17643],

        [57.139067, -2.172997],
        [57.137635, -2.177374],
        [57.137013, -2.180786],
        [57.139591, -2.183726],
        [57.140953, -2.176816],
        [57.142502, -2.178082]
    ]).addTo(mymap);


    /*Display lat/long coordinates - Development use only! */
    var popup = L.popup();
    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent(e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
    }
    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);


    /*Popups*/
    robertGordon.bindPopup("Robert Gordon University");
    pittodrie.bindPopup("Pittodrie Stadium");
    duthiePark.bindPopup("Duthie Park");
    unionTerraceGardens.bindPopup("Union Terrace Gardens")
    marischalCollege.bindPopup("Marischal College and Dancing Water Fountains")
    robertGordonCollege.bindPopup("Robert Gordon College and Art Gallery")
    aberdeenBeach.bindPopup("Aberdeen Beach")
    unionSquare.bindPopup("Union Square")
    victoriaPark.bindPopup("Victoria park")
    westburnPark.bindPopup("Westburn Park")
    hazleheadPark.bindPopup("Hazlehead Park")
    aberdeenUniversity.bindPopup("Aberdeen University")
    aberdeenHarbour.bindPopup("Aberdeen harbour")
        .addTo(mymap);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working with the turfjs library:
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5.1.6/turf.js"></script>`

Creating hex shape:

```
var hex = createHex(myMap.getCenter(),radius); //replace center with navigator point

function createHex(center,radius) {
        var centerp = turf.point([center.lng, center.lat]);
        var points = [];
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, 90));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, 150));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, -150));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, -90));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, -30));
        points.push(turf.destination(centerp, radius, 30));

        var hex = L.polygon([]);
        points.forEach((p)=>{
            hex.addLatLng([p.geometry.coordinates[1],p.geometry.coordinates[0]]);
        });
        return hex;
    }
```

To remove the hex from the "fog":

```
var fog = L.rectangle([[54.98652836571122, -1.542469837492442],[ 54.973032422136875, -1.4963848081781708]]);
var fogLayer = L.geoJSON(fog.toGeoJSON()).addTo(myMap);

function subtract() {
        var radius = 0.01;
        var hex = createHex(myMap.getCenter(),radius); //replace center with navigator point
        var templayer = L.geoJSON(turf.difference(fogLayer.getLayers()[0].toGeoJSON(), hex.toGeoJSON()));
        fogLayer.removeFrom(myMap);
        fogLayer = templayer.addTo(myMap)
    }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/6a4smLgt/

I hope you don't forget to check the answer ;)

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to respond and that looks superb and exactly what I'm trying to do! I'm quite new to leaflet and GeoJSON and getting a little over my head! I
When I add your code to my map it seems to not show the new layers at all on the map, I'll update my original code to show what I mean..

Comment: Pls check my answer

Comment: So am I understanding properly that i need to add:
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
In place of the get centre?

Comment: Look into this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/5uycgewx/

Comment: That is perfect and I have it implemented and working fully now. Thank you so much for all your help, it has helped me massively understand the concepts of leaflet and turf. If I could buy you a beer I would :)

Comment: When you upvote and accept the answer as correct, you helping me ;)

Comment: Hi sorry about the delay but I've accepted and upvoted, thanks again for the help :)